# Alternate options to combine rows data without "For Loop & If else" in python

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, for-loop, if-statement

I have to combine the rows based on the last word in the row,
Like

[data is in below format](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8kZn4.png)

Answer:

[Should combine like below](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S9zJh.png)

I have written the below code & it's working fine as expected, however, it becomes very slow when I have huge data (10K+ rows).

#split the string & take the last word

```
df["last_Word"] = df["Donor"].str.split().str[-1].str.lower()
df["Match_end"] = df["last_Word"].isin(align["KeyWords_end"].str.lower())
```

## Add two new columns in a data frame

```
df["Cleaned"]= ""
df["Mark"]= ""
```

### Align the text based on the last word & mark delete rows as "delete"

```
for i in range(len(df)):
    if ((df["Match_end"].iloc[i]== True) and (df["Match_end"].iloc[i+1]== True)):
        df["Mark"].iloc[i+1]= "delete"
        df["Mark"].iloc[i+2]= "delete"
        df["Cleaned"].iloc[i]= df["Donor"].iloc[i] + " " +df["Donor"].iloc[i+1]+ " " +df["Donor"].iloc[i+2]
```

### Delete the mark rows

```
df = df[~df['Mark'].str.contains("delete")]
```

### Update the newly created column

```
for i in range(len(df)):
    if len(df["Cleaned"].iloc[i])== 0:
    df["Cleaned"].iloc[i]= df["Donor"].iloc[i]
```

#Drop the unwanted columns

```
df.drop(["Donor","Mark","last_Word","Match_end"], axis = 1, inplace = True)
```

#Rename the newly created column

```
df.rename(columns= {"Cleaned": "Donor"},inplace = True)
```

Comment: Please provide a reproducible minimal input (as DataFrame) and the matching expected output.

Comment: Please provide your data as reproducible `DataFrame` constructor (text, **not images**!)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you want to combine the strings ending in "and" or "&", use a regex to identify those strings, then `groupby.agg`:

```
m = ~df['donor'].str.contains(r'(?:\band|&)\s*$').shift(fill_value=False)

df.groupby(m.cumsum(), as_index=False).agg({'donor': ' '.join})
```

Example output:

```
                      donor
0            ABC, DEF & GHI
1  JKL MNO and  PQR and STU
```

Used input:

```
          donor
0    ABC, DEF &
1           GHI
2  JKL MNO and 
3       PQR and
4           STU
```

Comment: Thank You so much Mozway. I really appreciate your effort to solve this problem. Thanks again!!